# NodeJS : Get a value of a hidden HTML input

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom

I am trying to get a value of an hidden input of an HTML file, with NodeJS.

The code in the HTML is :

```html
<input id="link-discord" readonly="readonly" type="text">
```

This is my NodeJS code :

```js
var afterLoad = require('after-load');
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

afterLoad('the url', function(html){
   
});
```

When I logged the html code I saw that the value of the input is empty, means it's hidden.

When I entered the website and opened the console, I ran the command `console.log(document.getElementById("link-discord").value);` and I got the value of this hidden input.

I tried using Cheerio but it didn't helped me.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure to understand, do you set a value at a certain point? Did you try to add a default value to your input (<input id="link-discord" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="valuetest">), it could help to run test. You said ' input is empty, means it's hidden' but an empty input does not mean it is hidden. Happy to help if you can precise a bit. Thanks

Comment: @C0G1T0 - Although the value is empty, it is have some value in it. How can I access the value if it's not in the HTML? Also, default value won't help me.

Comment: I think you should use Cheerio  package because its using is easier than other packages. For your problem I have a few question. After you get html code from the url, is its response type correct ? To understand this status, did you try to get any value or class except hidden input ? Isn't it just working for hidden input elements ?

Comment: @Halil, The response is correct and valid. After I got the response I tried to get the title and other things from the page and it was okay. I don't know much about Cheerio, and after looking some time about it in the github page of it I don't think it will help since it's not working with id. When I use JSDOM it returns me `HTMLInputValue` but it's empty.